# Mypy give incorrect type when accessing superclass attribute

Tags: python, mypy

I am trying to set the superclass attribute and access it in the subclass as follows:

```
class A:
    pass

class B(A):
    pass

class C:
    def __init__(self, param: A) -> None:
     self.store = param

class D(C):
    def __init__(self, param: B) -> None:
     super().__init__(param)
     reveal_type(self.store)
```

When I run mypy I get "Revealed type is 'test.A'" How do I get it to reference B rather than A in the subclass ?

Comment: The static type of `self.store` is A. And it has to be, or it wouldn't be the case that D is a subtype of C, because anyone who has a C instance (even if it's also a D instance) can legally set `c.store` to any A value, and your D code has to be able to handle that.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks a lot. So if I have a function in B, to call it in D, I would have to do an isinstance check first right ?

Comment: That depends on whether the attribute really is mutable (in which case yes) or not (in which case it’s a matter of the static type system being less expressive than the dynamic type system, so you might want to find a workaround instead). See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mypy is actually giving the right answer here. Covariant mutable attributes are not valid, so the type of `D._store` is in fact `A`. That probably sounds like a bunch of theoretical nonsense, so I'll explain it in more detail:

You're declaring that every `D` instance is-a `C` instance. And `C` has a mutable attribute named `_store` of type `A`. Therefore, it's legal to set the `_store` attribute at any time to any value of type `A`. Which means any use of a `D` instance has to be able to deal with the fact that its `_store` may be an `A`, not a `B`. Which means the type of `D._store` is `A`.

If your `C._store` is actually mutable, this is a real error in your code. Any time you want to use `B` methods on a `D._store`, you need to test with `isinstance` or `try`/`except`, after which of course you can safely rely on the fact that the value is a `B` (which will work even if the owner is not a `D`).

---

If, on the other hand, your `C._store` is immutable, what you want to do is valid (although you really should be using `__new__` rather than `__init__` to set it in that case), but because of a limitation in the current version of Mypy (or, rather, in the static type system for Python, which is less expressive than the dynamic type system, in some ways intentionally for simplicity, in other ways just because not everything has been thought through yet), you can't specify that fact explicitly. And I'm not sure whether it will ever be fixed in general (although specific cases like `dataclass` immutable attributes presumably will be at some point).

---

One option is to wrap the attribute in a (read-only) `@property`, [as documented for `Protocol` members](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#covariant-subtyping-of-mutable-protocol-members-is-rejected). But of course this adds some overhead to your implementation and complexity to your design.

Alternatively, thanks to [a bug in Mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/3208), you can actually work around this by lying to the type checker:

```
class C:
    _store: A
    def __init__(self, param: A) -> None:
     self._store = param

class D(C):
    _store: B
    def __init__(self, param: B) -> None:
     super().__init__(param)
     reveal_type(self._store)
```

If `_store` really is immutable, this will give you the right answer—until the bug is fixed. That may be OK for now, assuming you don't abuse the bug unsafely, and can stick with the current version of Mypy until a version comes out that lets you write things correctly.

If you can't stick to the current version of Mypy until then, you can always do this:

```
class C:
    _store: A: # type: ignore
    def __init__(self, param: A) -> None:
     self._store = param

class D(C):
    _store: B
    def __init__(self, param: B) -> None:
     super().__init__(param)
     reveal_type(self._store)
```

But of course this means you don't get any checking at all on `_store`; you can stick an `int` in there and it'll validate.

Comment: You can (now ?) use `Generic` typing :

`AT = TypeVar('AT', bound=A)`, `class C(Generic[AT]):` and `def __init__(self, param: AT) -> None:`